# getting syntax error with <= sign

Tags: python

When using this code:

```
     while str.find(target,key,n) != -1 and <= len(target):
```

I get a syntax error on 'less than or equal to sign'.  Why?

Comment: You want `while str.find(target,key,n) != -1 and str.find(target,key,n) <= len(target): ` the `<=` is a binary operator and there is no left operand here that is valid as you're using `and`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the double operand, you could rewrite it like:

```
if -1 < target.find(key, n) < len(target):
    pass
```

But that said, I don’t think find can ever return a value larger than the length of target.

Comment: Your comparison is not the same.  OP has str.find() _not equal to_ -1, while you have _greater than_ -1.

Comment: I really fail to see the semantic difference because find ALWAYS returns values in the range [-1, len(target)).

Comment: possibly more significant the OP had `<= len(target)` and you have `< len(target)`. The different comparison for `-1` may not matter, but there's no reason why you can't preserve both the original comparisons: `-1 != target.find(key,n) <= len(target)`

Comment: Again, `.find` will never return `len(target)`.  It will always return a value in the range [-1, len(target)) (note the trailing ')' to indicate exclusion).

Answer (score 0):

In English we can say "if X is not equal to Y and also less than Z", but Python syntax doesn't work that way.

If you want to compare a number to two other numbers, you have to repeat the original number in the second comparison.

i.e., instead of this:

```
if x != y and < z:
```

you must do this:

```
if x != y and x < z:
```

Comment: Python syntax does work that way although the repeated element has to be in the middle. `y != x <= z`

Comment: @Duncan Thanks for the tip!